# React Native Video is not automatically playing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a background video for my homepage on my app and I want it to be autoplaying and looping but all thats happening right now is the video is not playing at all.

Here is my code :

```
<Video
          source={require("../../Graphics/LoginVideo.mp4")}
          style={LoginPageStyle.backgroundVideo}
          muted={true}
          repeat={true}
          resizeMode={"cover"}
          rate={1.0}
          ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
        />
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
const LoginPageStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: "green",
    fontSize: 60,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 60,
  },

  bottom: {
    paddingTop: 450,
  },

  backgroundVideo: {
    height: height,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    alignItems: "stretch",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: Which libary do you use for `Video`?

Comment: Just initialize ```paused``` prop with ```false```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using `react-native-video` and with this kind of issues I would like to suggest that you should also check the API of the package first like this one[Package Props](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#configurable-props)

I think there might be an issue with your setup.

You can try to watch what is happening with the `onLoadStart` and `onLoad` callback to see if the video having a problem with loading.

```
<Video
          source={{
            uri: fullVideoUrl,
          }}
          volume={1.0}
          muted={true}
          paused={false}
          repeat={true}
          playInBackground={false}
          playWhenInactive={false}
          onLoadStart={() => {
            console.log('onLoadStart', new Date());
          }}
          onLoad={() => {
            console.log('onLoad', new Date());
          }}
        />
```

Comment: making TikTok like feed, I have a video on full screen and I paused the video at the first time because if I dont do that all videos run in the background and I hear multiple videos' voice, I used onViewableItemsChanged prop on flatlist and it is checking which is displaying and based on that pausing all others except the video which is displaying but this is taking time and video wait for few seconds and it dont look good for user experience can you tell me is there any other possible I can pause the other videos which are not showing.